# How can I script selective minimization of documents in text edit when several files may be open?

Tags: macos, command-line, automation, window-manager

From the Terminal, or in a shell file, I know how to open multiple files in a particular app in text edit from the command line and have all of their windows minimized like this:

```
open -a TextEdit.app ~/Documents/doc1.txt ~/Documents/doc2.txt ~/Documents/doc3.txt
osascript -e 'tell application "TextEdit" to set miniaturized of every window to true'
```

Is there a command to minimize not all of thow windows but **just a particular one of them** or equivalently, iterate over minimized windows to restore one by name like `~/Documents/doc1.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the windows you want to minimize first, and the other(s) afterwards.

```
open -a TextEdit.app ~/Documents/doc2.txt ~/Documents/doc3.txt
osascript -e 'tell application "TextEdit" to set miniaturized of every window to true'
open -a TextEdit.app ~/Documents/doc1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. (Of course - so obvious now that you say it!)